# Parsing XML from string C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-deserialization

I am trying to deserialize a string, `response.Content`, with this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><root><uri><![CDATA[http://api.bart.gov/api/stn.aspx?cmd=stns]]></uri><stations><station><name>12th St. Oakland City Center</name><abbr>12TH</abbr><gtfs_latitude>37.803664</gtfs_latitude><gtfs_longitude>-122.271604</gtfs_longitude><address>1245 Broadway</address><city>Oakland</city><county>alameda</county><state>CA</state><zipcode>94612</zipcode></station>
```

I am using this code to deserialize it:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Stations), new XmlRootAttribute("root"));
Stations result;
using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(response.Content))
{
    result = (Stations)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

I then have the `Stations` class declared here

```
[XmlRoot]
public class Stations
{

    [XmlElement]
    public string name;

}
```

However, my `name` is null.  Any idea why?

Comment: See this post for a good example of what you're trying to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While using `XmlSerializer` you should imitate all the xml structure with your classes.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "root")]
public class Root
{
    [XmlArray(ElementName = "stations"), XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "station")]
    public Station[] Stations { get; set; }
}

public class Station
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize your data in that way.

```
var data = ""; //your xml goes here
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
using (var reader = new StringReader(data))
{
    var root = (Root)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Stations is a list of Station objects. Stations does not have an element called Name, only Station does.

You should probably do something like

```
   public Station[] Stations
```

in the root-class.

Then define a new class called Station with a Name property.

Comment: Would I still need a Stations class?

Comment: You need a class to hold the Stations property. As long as it's decorated with the XmlRoot attribute I think it should work.

Comment: stations = (Station[])serializer.Deserialize(reader);
^getting an error on this line: Unable to cast object of type Station to Station[]

Comment: You should only have to deserialize the root-object (and let the serializer figure out the rest). See the example in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document

Answer (score 2):

`Stations` should not be a class, it should be a collection of `Station` elements.